# Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed when using ADO driver instead of DAO

Tags: excel, vba, odbc, ado, dao

I've installed on my Windows 10 machine an Oracle ODBC Instant Client 12 in order to connect my Excel macro to an Oracle database. My application is capable to connect to Oracle database by using DAO or ADO drivers. The connection to database works fine with DAO however when I try to use the ADO driver I'm getting the following error:

> Provider cannot be found.It may not be properly installed

How I a ADO connection is being setup in Excel macro:

```
Set Connection = VBA.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Connection.ConnectionString = IDatenbank_BuildConnectionString(ODBCConnection)
Call Connection.Open


IDatenbank_BuildConnectionString = "ODBC" & _
                                    ";DSN=" & ODBCConnection.Name & _
                                    ";Uid=" & ODBCConnection.User & _
                                    ";Pwd=" & ODBCConnection.Password
```

Any advice on how to work with ADO driver and avoid the error "Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed."

Excel 2016 is running on 32 bites on a Windows 10 machine used as a server. Microsoft ODBC is installed on 32 bits as the Excel instance.

What I have done until now:

- Installed and Oracle Client for ODBC 32 bits;
- Installed Access Database Engine for 32 bites;
- Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)

In client machine they can run together however seems not be true when server is used.

Comment: Without showing us the odbc string returned by `IDatenbank_BuildConnectionString(ODBCConnection)` we can't tell you much!

Comment: I have added details about the connection string, however I mention that the same connection string works without any issue on client machine with ADO driver but not on server machine whith ADO(only DAO works on server machine).

Comment: add `debug.print Connection.ConnectionString` in line 3

Comment: ODBC;DSN=US Company Int;Uid=ALA1Bala;Pwd=hihihi

Comment: Next step is to look at the content of the DSN file, and see if the specified driver is installed.

Comment: Were is this DNS file located? Do you mean the registry entry ? What I should look for, in order to access ADO driver ? Regards,

Comment: Do you mean : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Odbc\Odbc.ini\Odbc Data sources ?

Comment: DSN can be either in a file or in registry. It should contain the driver text. Personaly I always prefer to connect without DSN if I can (not always possible in larges companies).

Comment: driver text = driver name or is the exact connection string that could be used

Comment: Providers usually correspond to OLEDB and drivers correspond to ODBC. You are attempting ODBC but an provider error message is raised. Where are you using this connection string? Try replacing prefix `ODBC` with `OLEDB`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the "ODBC" in front of your connection string if you are using standard Oracle ODBC.

From your code, it contains the "ODBC":

```
'ODBC;DSN=xxx;Uid=yyy;Pwd=zzz
IDatenbank_BuildConnectionString = "ODBC" & _
                                    ";DSN=" & ODBCConnection.Name & _
                                    ";Uid=" & ODBCConnection.User & _
                                    ";Pwd=" & ODBCConnection.Password

'It should be "DSN=xxx;Uid=yyy;Pwd=zzz" only without "ODBC" in front
IDatenbank_BuildConnectionString = "DSN=" & ODBCConnection.Name & _
                                    ";Uid=" & ODBCConnection.User & _
                                    ";Pwd=" & ODBCConnection.Password
```